# listing parameters or using a dictionary

Tags: c++, rosparam, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In C++, is there a way to list parameters on the parameter server, optionally those in a particular namespace? Alternatively, can I use a dictionary/map?

I want to put a mapping name/number in a yaml file loaded by roslaunch, and my node should be able to list the names and retrieve the associated number. rosparam list can do that, and associated with grep I can retrieve only the parameters I want. can I do that in C++ directly. the parameter server c++ API does not seem to provide that, or is it hidden? Can it be added in future releases?

I tried using a dictionary but it was expended in a list of parameters instead of being a dictionary data structure, i.e. those 2 yaml files yielded the same result

```
channel_numbers: {applanix: 0, radar: 1, trimble: 5, velodyne: 10}
```

and

```
channel_numbers:
  applanix: 0
  radar: 1
  trimble: 5
  velodyne: 10
```

I would like something like:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
vector<string> parameters = nh.list_parameters("channel_numbers");
// and then for each parameter in parameters get its value...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47109/listing-parameters-or-using-a-dictionary/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The functionality is there by using [`XmlRpcValue`](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/doc/classXmlRpc_1_1XmlRpcValue.html) versions of the getParam functions.

An example of how to get a list is available: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists.

If you need more, i.e. dictionaries then refer to the  [`XmlRpcValue`](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/doc/classXmlRpc_1_1XmlRpcValue.html) docs.

TypeStruct is a dictionary. There is hidden functionality that the official docs do not list and afaik was added to ROS. For a dictionary there are begin() and end() functions that allow to iterate over the dict entries. You can find an example here: http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/freiburg_tools/rxparamedit/src/xmlRpcTreeItem.cpp#180

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on 2015-04-30**:
The links end with a period accidentally. I don't have enough rep to edit.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-04-30**:
I removed the dot.

**Comment by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) on 2015-08-18**:
Thank you so much for sharing the example from alufr-ros package ;)

**Comment by [blakejwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29253/blakejwc/) on 2018-04-17**:
Is there an updated link to the example.  I couldn't find the TypeStruct example on the google code archive.  I'm trying to print the params used by a given node.